# Overlay values corresponding lat and long in a shape file in R

Tags: r, geospatial

I want to overlay lat-long corresponding wmo points from excel over shapefile in R. I went through others' problems, but still, I am unable to do it. I have tried this code but not working. Please help.

```
shapestate <- read_sf(file.path(dir_ls$input_dir, 'shapefile'), 'State_sim')
plot(st_geometry(shapestate), col="darkblue", main="Tahoe HUC8", axes=TRUE)

wmo<-read.xlsx(file.path(dir_ls$input_dir, 'cyclone', 'checking wind speed.xlsx'))

coordinates(wmo) <- ~ LAT + LON
IND<-spTransform(shapestate, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))


points(wmo$LAT ~ wmo$LON, col = "red", cex = 1, pch = 19)
```

The shapefile and values corresponding lat-long in excel are shared in this given link.
[shapefile and wmo values in excel](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eRF5eY1EtxQuhIFr1CLOR0PN4TyGswM0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me help you. As the `shp` file alone is not enough to read it properly, I will use `geodata` package to read the boundaries. In your case:

```r
sf::st_read("path_to_shapefile.shp") |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot()
```

should be enough.

With `sf` package and its functions:

```r
geodata::gadm("India", path = tempdir()) |>
  sf::st_as_sf() |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot()

readxl::read_excel("/home/sapi/Downloads/checking wind speed.xlsx") |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("LON", "LAT"), crs = 4326) |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(pch = 16, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Or with `terra` package:

```r
geodata::gadm("India", path = tempdir()) |>
  terra::plot()

readxl::read_excel("/home/sapi/Downloads/checking wind speed.xlsx") |>
  terra::vect(geom = c("LON", "LAT"), crs = "EPSG:4326") |>
  terra::plot(pch = 16, col = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Please have a look on sf::st_read() and/or terra::vect() functions to read your shapefile.

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>